# Editing Twilio TwiML using API or HTTP POST

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

My company uses Twilio Flex as our phone system and I was recently tasked with setting up a feature that will let us edit a TwiML voice message that plays before our normal voice message. This TwiML message will be changed through a Twilio bot that I've published in our Microsoft Teams.

The reason for this is so that our support desk can add a short message in the lines of "We're currently experiencing issues with X" before our normal "Welcome to [Company] support" message.

If TwiML's can be edited using HTTP POST/PUT or Twilio's API this should be a trivial matter, but so far I've not been able to figure out how.

I couldn't find any reference to this in the [API doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#twiml-elements), so I decided that HTTP POST would be the way to go. Using this as a start off point, I'm able to retrieve my TwiML using HTTP GET:

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132187--Not-Authorized-error-when-trying-to-view-TwiML-Bin-URL

```
const axios = require('axios');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const accountSidFlex = process.env.accountSidFlex;
const authTokenFlex = process.env.authTokenFlex;

var URL = 'https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' + '?AccountSid=' + accountSidFlex
    var twilioSig = crypto.createHmac('sha1', authTokenFlex).update(new Buffer(URL, 'utf-8')).digest('Base64')
var config = {
    headers:{
    'X-TWILIO-SIGNATURE': twilioSig
    }
}

axios.get(
    URL,config  
).catch(error => console.log(error))
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
})
```

response.data shows the TwiML's current XML content.

My attempts at a POST only gives the same output as the GET, while PUT gives 405 Method Not Allowed.

```
var URL = 'https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' + '?AccountSid=' + accountSidFlex
var twilioSig = crypto.createHmac('sha1', authTokenFlex).update(new Buffer(URL, 'utf-8')).digest('Base64')

var config = {
    headers:{
    'X-TWILIO-SIGNATURE': twilioSig,
    'Content-Type': 'text/xml'
    }
}

var xml = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\
<Response><Play digits="www"/>\
<Say voice="alice">"We are currently experiencing X related issues". </Say>\
</Response>';

axios.post(
    URL,xml,config
)
.catch(error => console.log(error))
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
})
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to change a specific TwiML using either HTTP methods or the Twilio-API, so that we can use it in out Studio Flow. We'd just keep it silent until we need to add something to it and revert back to silent once the issues have passed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot currently change the contents of TwiML Bins, Studio Flows, or Twilio Functions programatically. I believe the key functionality you are looking for is a way to dynamically update the messaging (Say/Play Widget) in a Studio flow based on some condition.

One way is to use a Function Widget to retrieve a Twilio Sync document for the message, returning the message as JSON and have the Say/Play widget play that message. You can find the [Twilio Sync REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sync/api/documents) examples for Add, Modify, and Retrieve in the associated document.

You can retrieve the parsed response using variable syntax detailed here, https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library#run-function.